# Why did Darusya kick Ivan out?

Tags: ukrainian-language, maria-matios, sweet-darusya

At one point, Ivan was dragged before a subset of the town council, who had him thrown in administrative lockup for 15 days on a variety of obviously ridiculous charges. After he got out, Maria irrationally shouted that he "shouldn't have done it." Ivan angrily demands to know exactly what he shouldn't have done. Darusya subsequently develops a severe headache and eventually, in one of the rare times where she speaks, told Ivan to leave (which he does). Why did she do that?